# draw a rectangle over an image

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans-7, rectangles

I have tried the code below for drawing a rectangle on an image(jLabel) but its not drawing. Please help to solve this.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

   this.paintComponent(g);
   g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

   g.drawRect(n,n1,40,40);

}



private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)   
{                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    k=0;
    f=jLabel1.getMousePosition();
    n=f.x;
    n1=f.y;
    n=n+p/2;
    n1=n1+(q/2-25);
    repaint(n,n1,40,40);     
}
```

Comment: `jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)` use an undecorated button with an `ActionListener` instead.  It will look like a `JLabel` but be focusable, allow mnemonics and also respond to keyboard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have infinite recursion there, and will get a stack overflow.
This:

```
this.paintComponent(g)
```

should be instead:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Comment: sir can you tell how to remove the drawn rectangle from the image?That is when the second click performed a new rectangle will be drawn ,at the same time the previous rectangle want to remove.

Comment: @spc The drawing is destructive - what is drawn in `paintComponent()` is everything that gets drawn. So you can set a flag to draw a rectangle in `jLabel1MouseClicked()` and toggle it at each click. Then in `paintComponent()` draw the rectangle only if that flag is true. Every click must also call `repaint()` so that the showing/hiding works as intended.